# Installation problems of PySCIPOpt on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, scip

when I run `pip install pyscipopt` I get the following error:

```
 build\lib.win32-3.7\pyscipopt\scip.cp37-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 311 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\mwars\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\mwars\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wsiojhnh\\pyscipopt\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mwars\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xtl04q1v\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mwars\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wsiojhnh\pyscipopt\
```

I set the `SCIPOPTDIR` and I added `ScipOptSuite\bin` to my `PATH` var

Comment: Can you execute ```scip``` on the command line? This way you can check whether the ```PATH``` is set correctly. What are the 311 unresolved externals? Did you install the latest SCIPOptSuite 6.0.1?

Comment: Also, I very much recommend to use Anaconda on Windows: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: @mattmilten I did download it and I get this error when I try to install with it not pip

Comment: `Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.`

Comment: `SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))`

Comment: @mattmilten this is a link to the full pip error https://pastebin.com/0BPhvujK

Comment: Please create a clean conda environment and install PySCIPOpt there. I just tried it and it worked fine. Also, you still need to run `pip install  pyscipopt` - just within a virtual environment.

Comment: @mattmilten I tried to make an clean conda environment here's what happened https://pastebin.com/Twe6qeAS

Comment: Well, this seems to be a bigger issue, that is not connected to PySCIPOpt.

Comment: you have linker error [LNK2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=msvc-170)